# how to reload aot compiled classes without resetting the repl?

Tags: clojure

I've defined a java class using `gen-class` and it get compile everytime I start the repl. However, if I wish to make changes to the class, I find that I have to restart and recompile the class. Is there anyway to do this without closing down the repl?

#### An example

I am working on this https://github.com/zcaudate/hara/blob/master/src/hara/ova/impl.clj

and there is a line in project. clj

```
:aot [hara.ova.impl]
```

So say the file is already loaded and I can do:

```
(import hara.ova.Ova)
(def a (Ova.))
```

I wanted to add another method `bar` to the class, I just wish to define `-bar` in the `hara.ova.impl` namespace, call a `compile-gen-class` function to reload the class and then do
this without reloading the repl:

```
(import hara.ova.Ova)
(def a (Ova.))
(.bar a)
```

right now, C-c C-k doesn't allow that.

Comment: If you're using Emacs for both editing and NREPL, just go in the source file where you defined the class and hit C-c C-k. If you're not using Emacs and NREPL, then you should start.

Comment: oh really? I am using that. I was using swank before and was sure C-c C-k did not work. Has anything changed or am I just delusional?

Comment: nope... I just tried it doesn't work for `gen-class`

Comment: OK. I'll look into it in the morning at work and see what I can find out. Can you share more details about your project structure?

Comment: I've updated my question with an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the `compile` function on the namespace.

`(ns test)
(gen-class :name test.Cls)
(comment (compile 'test))`

The call to compile needs to be commented out so it won't recursively call itself. I often leave these in my development files to quickly recompile definitions by evaluating that compile expression.